# How to show an image in featherlight lightbox from an ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to open an image with Featherlight at a specific place in
my html page from an ajax request:

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Search</title>  
        <meta charset="utf-8" />  
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  
    </head>  
        <body>  
                <ol>  
                    <li class item >  
                        **<div id="mylightbox">This div will be opened in a lightbox</div>**  
                    </li>  
                </ol>   
        <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.4.0/release/featherlight.min.js"  
        type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </body>  
</html>





function ShowPicture()  
{
    $('div#message').html("");  
    $.post('ajax/photo.php', {  
        dataType:'binary',  
        func: "getAffichePhoto"  
    },   
    function(return_data)  
    {  
        $.get('js/picture.jpg', function(data) {  
            **$('div#mylightbox').featherlight(data);**      
        });      
    }, "json" );  
}
```

Somebody know the syntax for this king of code ?

I try many, many test, none is working. I must miss something.
My syntax is not the right one and I cannot find the way to
do it right.

Something is wrong with my tag and I do know how
the bind together the HTML part with the jQuery side.

For test purpose I use temporaly $.get('js/picture.jpg', function(data)
witch return a clean jpeg file.

Anybody know where I can find example for this type code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//Initially disable featherlight
$.featherlight.autoBind = false;


$(document).ready(function(){

var $elem = $('div#mylightbox');
var url = '';

  $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : url,            
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function (data) {
      //setDataAttribute after Ajax Success 
      myFunction(data, $elem);
    },
    error : function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {           
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
});

function myFunction(data, $elem){
  $elem.attr('data-featherlight', data);//here data == img.src

   //init featherlight after setting data-featherlight
  $elem.featherlight();
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/TheEnd/pen/YWvJdb?editors=0010